# Why is maven failing to execute javac in this instance?

Tags: java, maven

On windows 7. So the following commands work fine:

- mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
- mvn install

However if I run "mvn clean," then "mvn install" fails and says it cannot execute javac "because the system cannot find the path specified."

This can be fixed if I run "mvn install -Djava="my jdk home"."

So why do I get this error unless I explicitly state the path to my jdk even though my java home is the same and mvn eclipse:eclipse works?

Comment: Set your JAVA_HOME variable. Furthermore i would suggest not to use 'mvn eclise:eclipse' cause in the meantime m2e in eclipse is better if you using Keppler or LUNA of Eclipse.

Comment: @khmarbaise I believe my JAVA_HOME variable is set because, if I run "echo %JAVA_HOME%" it gives the correct path.

Comment: Is your JAVA_HOME pointing to a JDK or JRE?

Comment: @JoshGhiloni it points to ..\Java\jdk1.6.0_37

Comment: and if you run "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac" ? If it's in C:\Program Files, is the value quoted?

Comment: @JoshGhiloni "echo %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac%" gives "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac%" Yes, the value is quoted for C:\Program Files

Comment: You have an extra % at the end -- and don't do an echo, actually run it. With no arguments, if the file is there, you should get the default usage statement for javac.

Comment: @JoshGhiloni I think you found my issue. When I run that it gives: " 'C:\Program' is not recnogized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' Where do I go from here then?

Comment: What does `mvn --version` show?

Comment: @khmarbaise mvn --version shows the apache maven versions, the current java version, the current java home variable which ends in jre, the default locale which is en_us, and the current os.

Comment: That was not helpfull. I know what it show. Please post the output into your question cause it will help to see where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry here is the output.

Java version: 1.6.0_37

Java home: C:\Program Files <x86>\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre

Comment: @StickStack -- reset your Java home. do `set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37"`